# Retain Overlaid FigCaption on Click of the Image

Tags: css

**Current:** I have 10 individual images with figcaption and they are used as a checkbox. When user rolls over the mouse on the image, the figcaption is shown on the image. Once the user selects the image and moves out the mouse, the figcaption disappears.

**Issue & Expected outcome:** I am trying to achieve that once the user selects the image, the figcaption should stay instead of disappearing (only for the chosen image). Not sure where I am going wrong.

```css
/* for image as a checkbox. */

input.img-checkbox[type=radio],
input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
input.img-checkbox[type=radio]+label,
input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox]+label {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input.img-checkbox[type=radio]:checked+label,
input.img-checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* until here */

/* to display the figure caption on mouse over */

figure {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

.cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
}
/* until here */
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id='1' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='10073' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='1' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='1' class='FakeClass'>Amirul Azri Bin Ishak</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='2' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='3688' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='2' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='2' class='FakeClass'>Bacon Anak Kendu</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='3' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='9492' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='3' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='3' class='FakeClass'>Fadhlur Rahman</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='4' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='6912' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='4' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='4' class='FakeClass'>Faridah Bte Abdul Aziz</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='5' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='10135' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='5' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='5' class='FakeClass'>Hisham Bin Kamal Mustafa</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='6' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='3705' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='6' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='6' class='FakeClass'>Hong Wai Heng</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='7' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='9377' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='7' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='7' class='FakeClass'>Jufri Bin Othman</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='8' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='3698' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='8' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='8' class='FakeClass'>Kendy Albert Kiim</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='9' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='10049' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='9' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='9' class='FakeClass'>Kesava Kumar Krishnan</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <input id='10' class="img-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectTipo" value='10074' />
    <figure class='cap-bot'>
      <label for='10' class='FakeClass'>
        <img src='images/employees/noimage.jpg' style="border:1px solid;" />
      </label>
      <figcaption>
        <label for='10' class='FakeClass'>Khairil Hazrin Bin Kasbolah</label>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</form>
```

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try leveraging the checkbox. I think you might actually have the perfect solution set up and just don't know it. Judging from your code, we need to find a path to the figcaption from the input. It looks like this could work:

```
.img-checkbox:checked + figure figcaption {
  opacity:1;
}
```

This will select figcaptions of a figure directly adjacent to a checked input, and make its opacity 1.

Comment: Thanks James but it did not work...tried with different combinations

Comment: Look at this jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yp7tLrpw/). It works if the caption is clicked. It works best on the first image because I copied and pasted your code and the figcaption is bleeding onto the lower images.

Comment: So I think the question is how easy do you want your label to be clickable? Maybe make it larger so a user doesn't have to click on the text but can click on the whole image.

Comment: Even in the jsfiddle, when you click on the one of the image and then move the mouse to another image, the earlier image figcaption is gone. I want the caption to retain on the earlier image.

Comment: I don't know man. That's not happening for me. Working fine except for the caption bleed. I think without using javascript using checkboxes is your best bet. I definitely think the structure needs to be worked around so that the boxes don't bleed over each other. Best of luck.

Comment: Remember what I said too, it was working when you clicked on the caption text, not the image itself. This is because of how you sized your labels.

Comment: Thanks James, I understand what you mean by the caption text. Let me see how to fix it..